# Does a Truecrypt file container really eats a lot of space from start?

Tags: windows-7, truecrypt

I just created a fresh new container I notice it already consumed more than half (6MB free out of 16MB).

I also checked out my old container, my files are only only 10MB but it says 49MB is used.

Is this really the expected result?

If yes, how do I estimate the real free space when creating a new container? (e.g., if I want 16MB free space how big should I create the container from Truecrypt?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested and if you create a 16 MB TrueCrypt file you get 6 MB free left if you format in NTFS and 15.7 MB free if you format in FAT.

NTFS is not meant to be used with partitions that are that small. It's using journaling that makes it much more reliable than FAT but the journal takes some space and it will be noticeable with such a small partition.

You could use exFAT, it's better than FAT but only usable with Vista and later (or XP if you install a patch). If you don't have a requirement to use NTFS (journaling or permissions) it will do the job.

If you need to use NTFS just make the TrueCrypt file a bit bigger.